# How to cancel stream CopyToAsync when no bytes are written for longer than given time period

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'd like to detect that Stream.CopyToAsync operation stalls and detect that when for longer than 1 minute no bytes are copied.

How that could be done?

Comment: I expect you could make a timeout more fine-grained by implementing your own CopyToAsync [based on Microsoft's code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs#L169-L174), although I'm not sure how you can really separate timing out the read from timing out from data being received without very small buffer sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to periodically check the `Stream.Length`, If the there is no progress, cancel the using `CancellationTokenSource`. Here is the code which basically uses the timer to periodically check if there is any progress with copying.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
var copyingCompleted = false;
var copyBufferSize = 4096;
var interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;
var initialTimeoutMilliseconds = -1;//inifinite
var timer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed,null,initialTimeoutMilliseconds,interval);
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
long streamLength = 0;

Stream srcStream = null;//should be your sourceStream
Stream dstStream = null;//should be your destination stream
await Copy(srcStream,dstStream,cts.Token);

public async Task Copy(Stream src,Stream dst, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
    timer.Change(interval,interval);
    try{
        await src.CopyToAsync(dst,copyBufferSize, cancellationToken);
    }
    finally{
        copyingCompleted = true;
    }
}

public void OnTimerElapsed(object state){
    if(copyingCompleted){
        //stop the timer
        timer.Change(-1,-1);
        return;
    }

    //check if the copying has progressed since the last interval callback was invoked
    if(dstStream.Length > streamLength){
        //copy has progressed, I will check you in the next interval
        streamLength = dstStream.Length;
        return;
    }

    //you didn't make any progress, I am cancelling the copy process
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

This is not the complete implementation, you need to take care of disposing the disposable resources, including `Timer`, `CancellationTokenSource` and `Stream`s

Comment: This is a clever idea, I need to make sure it works with HttpResponseMessage streams when buffering is disabled

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the overload of CopyToAsync that takes a cancellation token.

How to do it is explained here: [Cancel async tasks after a period of time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time)